# Taking into account the mutual inductive coupling analytically in LTSPICE

Tags: ltspice, simulation, transient, mutual-inductance

I am trying to take into account the mutual inductive coupling between three turns in LTspice differently. Instead of defining the inductive coupling coefficient K, I am using the analytical expression of the induced emf in the turn: emf_1 = M_i_j * d(I_j)/dt (1) by using behavioral voltage sources. Please refer to the figure below for illustration:
[image]

To do so and to validate my model I am comparing the voltage distributions in both cases (where the mutual inductive coupling is taken into account by LTspice and when I introduce the well known expression of emf (see equation (1) above)). In frequency domain, all seems to be good. However, when I run my simulation in time domain I get the same voltage distribution, expect for the input current of the input voltage: It is of 10^38A values!!!!!
[image]

How can I explain this? Or said differently, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your alternative implementation does not appear to follow the correct sign/dot notation as your first (k-coupled) circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for the remark. I will correct it and check if it's the reason why.

Comment: @Andyaka Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing, you are referring to the sign of the used behavioral sources, right?

Comment: Yes, I think B4 and B6 should be inverted but, that entirely depends on the pin numbers of the inductors being consistent.

Comment: @Andyaka I have done as you instructed and I still have the same value of the input current

Comment: Well, you should really confirm or deny my suspicions. I can't categorically state they are wrong but I can say that there isn't enough information in the picture to make that determination.

Comment: @Andyaka can you please tell me what information is needed so I can edit my post?

Comment: Just read at what I say in comments - the current directions are unclear i.e. I(L6) might be positive or it might be negative depending on L6's pin numbers.

Comment: @Andyaka I have taken time to understand your comment. You were right it was a pin number  problem. Thank you so much! Should I respond to my own answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I said in comments: -

> **Your alternative implementation does not appear to follow the correct
> sign/dot notation as your first (k-coupled) circuit.**

Meaning that if you naturally assumed that all the inductors of the alternate implementation had pin 1 (shown in red) in the same place i.e. like this: -

[image]

...Then there are some sign errors in your formulas (purple stuff).

> *@Andyaka I have taken time to understand your comment. You were right it was a pin number problem. Thank you so much!*

Comment: Signs corrected and a logic amount of current measured. Thank you!