# The function 'ddt' in LTspice frequency simulation

Tags: ltspice, simulation, mutual-inductance

I have previously used the time derivative defined by LTspice in a time domain simulation, and I was wondering if this function could be used in frequency domain. If yes, what does it do exactly?
I would like to introduce the mutual inductive coupling between inductors in the frequency domain without having to use the LTspice defined coefficient K.

This question is a continuation of the one seen [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/573165/taking-into-account-the-mutual-inductive-coupling-analytically-in-ltspice/573192#573192).

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from running that schematic in an `.AC` analysis and finding out for yourself. You'll see that it works just fine, just line `idt()` (or `sdt()`).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I have discovered that in *.AC* analysis the *ddt()* does not work since there is no definition of time whatsoever. I instead used an e symbol (a voltage  dependent voltage source) from which I compute s.*I(R). However, in *.TRANS* simulations, I have noticed that the *ddt* does not always work as expected and yields error "Time step too small". Any ideas for a workaround please?

Comment: `.AC` has absolutely no problems with `ddt()`. Or `sdt()`. You're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen You mean I can still do a time derivative in frequency domain? I can, I have no error message, but the results are not valid. I don't know how to share my circuit with you here...

Comment: That sounds like [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) problems. That's where the circuit fails, numerically, but continues. Since the (previous) data that it relies upon are also NaN, all the subsequent data points are NaNs. Why not try a simple `AC` source with a behavioural source afterwards that performs a simple `ddt()` on it; you'll see it works just fine. Try breaking up your circuit, use VCCS+L instead of `ddt()`. Seeing the link in your OP, make sure that the behavioural expressions don't use direct current feedback, (see the manual: *LTspice > Circuit Elements > B.*, 3rd bullet).

Comment: As for sharing a schematic here, you can copy-pase the contents of the `.asc` file (be sure to use ``` delimiters for the block of text). If 3rd party libraries or symbols exist, do the same with the `.asy`, or `.sub`, or `.lib`, etc (but only the relevant entries, i.e. if it's a library with 1000 subcircuits then only use the needed ones).